# How can i retopologize mesh to fix shading errors

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to model the object shown in the second picture, and for some reason I can't find a way to get an accurate representation of the object while maintaining good topology. I've tried booleans and fixing the topology later, but that gave weird shading issue's. I've tried to manually cut out the horizontal cylinder out of the vertical one with the knife tool, but that didn't work either. I've watched a whole lot of Youtube video's about merging/joining object together but nothing really seams to work for this model.

At this moment there are a lot of N-gons and i don't know how to get rid of it. Does anybody know a way to fix the topology of this model?

[image]

[image: My attempt]

Object I'm trying to model
[image: Object I'm trying to model]

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share .blend files.